# How to access the local MYSQL DB instance from Pivotal Could Foundry App?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have an application which is already deployed to Pivotal Could Foundry/Pivotal Web Services. I need to connect the DB service which is running my local machine.

I can use the MySQL service (ClearDb) in my Application. But I need to use the local DB service due to some heavy load of the DB. Can  I use "cf cups" ?

Thanks,
Mr.M

Answer (score 0):

Yes, issue your cups command from the CLI:

```
cf cups sensordb -p “jdbUrl,user,password"
```

You will be prompted for the three parameters. Enter them in this format:

**jdbcUrl**: mysql://mymachine.domain.com:3306/demodb?reconnect=true

**user**: user

**password**: password